# summing the column till the required column is satisfied

Tags: pandas, numpy

pandas dataframe df and columns are client=[123,123,456,456,456] , scrip=['A','B','A','X','Z'] , Value=[1000,5000,2000,15000,70000], amt require=[500,500,50000,50000,50000,50000] from this need to create a new column with logic as in client 123, amt require from first row itself is satisfied based on value so for first record we will take for second we will ignore and case second case same is from third record. in some case it me summing till the record of value.

i tried cumsum() of pandas but it is not working and also cummax()

I want a new column as remark.
In first row it should reflect will consider in second row not required already satisfied. As for client 123 the required amt is 500 and first row has value more than 500 i.e. 1000.
In client 456 also 3rd record has sufficient value. If there is no such record that is greater than or equal to amt require, we will check the cumulative sum of record till we reach amt require.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?  A new column?  A separate list?

Comment: Please provide a valid input (you have 6 items in "amt require") and the exact expected output.

Comment: Please provide the explicit output. It's less ambiguous than a description

Comment: Please provide code examples for input and expected output and format them as code. The editor window has a button for that. See also: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your logic right, this is how you do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "client": [123, 123, 456, 456, 456],
    "scrip": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'X', 'Z'],
    "Value": [1000, 5000, 2000, 15000, 70000],
    "amt_require": [500, 500, 50000, 50000, 50000]
})

df["remark"] = ""

for client, group in df.groupby("client"):
    amt_require_client = group["amt_require"].iloc[0]
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if amt_require_client <= 0:
            df.at[i, "remark"] = "Not Required (Amt already satisfied)"
            continue

        if row["Value"] >= amt_require_client:
            df.at[i, "remark"] = "Will consider"
            row["Value"] -= amt_require_client
            amt_require_client = 0
            continue

        cumsum = 0
        for j in range(i):
            if df.at[j, "client"] != client:
                continue
            cumsum += df.at[j, "Value"]
            if cumsum >= amt_require_client:
                df.at[i, "remark"] = "Will consider (Amt satisfied by cumulative sum)"
                amt_require_client = 0
                break

        if amt_require_client > 0:
            df.at[i, "remark"] = "Not Required (Insufficient Value)"

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
   client scrip  Value  amt_require                                remark
0     123     A   1000          500                         Will consider
1     123     B   5000          500  Not Required (Amt already satisfied)
2     456     A   2000        50000     Not Required (Insufficient Value)
3     456     X  15000        50000     Not Required (Insufficient Value)
4     456     Z  70000        50000                         Will consider
```

Basiclly, you loop through the entire dataframe and first heck if the required amount has already been satisfied. If Check if the row's value is greater than or equal to the required amount, you tag it as `Will consider`, if not, you check the cumulative sum until the required amount is satisfied and so on.

Comment: amt require is at client level so for client 123 only 500 is required.  so only in first row consider should reflect as from first row 500 is available

Comment: @Foram Chck if my update maps your question